# Retrieve paths from a graph split at nodes with a degree >= 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

When I add paths to a graph:

```
>>> graph = nx.MultiGraph()  # Needs to be MultiGraph/MultiDiGraph.
>>> graph.add_path([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> graph.add_path([2,6,7])
>>> graph.add_path([4,8,9,10,11])
```

What can I do to retrieve my paths split at nodes with a degree >= 3? So that I get:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4], [4, 8, 9, 10, 11], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: When you're trying to "retrieve" them - do you assume you know what the original paths are and you're just trying to break them at degree at least 3 nodes?  Or are you looking in the graph to find paths between degree at least 3 nodes (and degree 1) nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know your paths in advance. If you actually start out with a graph and want to "strip" it into paths, let me know. I would suggest another approach then.

Here is would I came up with, might not be the fastest or most elegant way, but it should work:

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.MultiGraph()
paths = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,6,7], [4,8,9,10,11]]

for path in paths:
    graph.add_path(path)

splitted_paths = []    

# generate list of nodes at which the paths are to be splitted
splitting_nodes = [node for node in graph if graph.degree(node)>=3]

for path in paths:
    # find the splitting nodes in the current path
    splitting_nodes_in_path = [node for node in splitting_nodes if node in path]
    for splitting_node in splitting_nodes_in_path:
        # get remaining path up to the current splitting node
        path_piece = path[:path.index(splitting_node)+1]
        if len(path_piece) > 1:
            splitted_paths.append(path_piece)
        # overwrite current path with the remaining path
        path = path[path.index(splitting_node):]
    # get the remaining piece from the last splitting node until the end of the current path
    if len(path) > 1:        
        splitted_paths.append(path)

print splitted_paths
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT 1:** removed an unnecessary for loop and added some missing code lines

---

**EDIT 2:** If you need to start out with a graph, like @marcus comment suggests, and want to have two paths in the given list of paths "glued together" if they are connected without a node of degree >= 3, you have to use a different approach. I don't have the time to fully code what I have in mind to solve this, but here is a sketch of what I would try:

- write a function `cut(graph, node)` that takes a Networkx graph and a nodelabel and replaces `node` by degree(`node`) new nodes, each connected to one of `node`s neighbors (one has to think of a clever way to name the new nodes, so that it's clear in the end where they came from)
- apply `cut()` to all nodes of degree >= 3 and end up with a disconnected graph, where each component is one of the desired splitted paths

The following Networkx functions could maybe be helpful for that: [`remove_node()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_node.html#remove-node), [`subgraph()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html#subgraph). [`all_simple_paths()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#all-simple-paths), [`predecessor()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.predecessor.html#predecessor) and the [`Operators`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/algorithms.operators.html#operators).

Comment: A note - your first for loop could be rewritten as:  `splitting_nodes = [node in graph if graph.degree(node)>=3]`

Comment: Doing it this way networkx isn't needed. (http://hastebin.com/rulitadabo.py). But the reason why I am trying to use networkx is that for sth. like `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 10, 11], [5, 12, 13]]` I want to get `[..., [2, 3, 4, 5], ...]` and not `[..., [2, 3], [3, 4, 5], ...]`. (I am working with Openstreetmap data and ids are random...)

Comment: Thanks @Joel, I wrote the code in a hurry. Changed it.

Comment: That's a nice version @marcus, much faster then mine. But if I understand you correctly you actually do need to start out with the graph structure and not the seperated paths list. I will try to come up with a second version. Nice to know, that this is for Openstreetmap! But what do you mean with the "ids are random"? That shouldn't effect the problem, right?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I thought networkx could have a method that let's me split a graph at nodes with a degree >= 3 and returns a list of subgraphs where every node has a degree of 1 or 2. Then I could just throw every way in my openstreetmap data set at it and it would return ways that are just split at nodes with degree of >= 3. Which is not true for data you download from osm as everybody can split every way everywhere and no algorithm fixes those changes. Nevertheless, I guess I can/will code this myself not using networkx at all. As far as the random id thing is concerned you're right btw.

Comment: At least I didn't find anything @marcus. The only related functions I found are the [k-core algorithms](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/algorithms.core.html#module-networkx.algorithms.core), but I couldn't think of a way to make them do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

first: why do you need MultiGraph? From what you are saying, a simple DiGraph would suffice; MultiGraphs are only needed if you want two different connections from e.g. node 4 and 10, with different attributes.

A lot of nx functions don't work with MultiGraphs, but if DiGraphs will work, then you could try `weakly_connected_subcomponent_graphs`. I don't have time to completely code it up, but this should be the algorithm:

1- Get all the nodes with degree >=3 (this is easy, and left as an exercise to the reader), along with any node connected to it (predecessors + successors).
2- Remove the nodes from the graph. This should leave only nodes with degree <= 2.
3- Call weakly_connected_subcomponent_graphs. This will return the forest of remaining graphs that aren't connected to each other.
4- But the nodes with degree >=3 aren't included; you'll need to add them back. You have to add both nodes and edges; you can either just get the node list from the weakly connected subtree, add in the connection nodes, and ask the original graph for a subgraph, or add the edges yourself.

This should be reasonably fast.

Comment: As I said I am working with OSM data. That is why I am using MultiDiGraphs (right now). But I had also written something that was fast enough for my graph. (Just ignore the '_'...) http://hastebin.com/namenezoqa.py